# Distribution of $e^{XY}$ when $X,Y$ are independent $U[0,1]$ random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

How can I find the probability distribution of $Z=e^{XY}$ given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have a uniform probability distribution in $[0,1]$?

**My work up to now:**

The probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$ are $f_{X}(x)=f_{Y}(y)=1$, thus, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1$.  I also know that $Z$ can take values from $1$ to $e$.

I tried to find the probability that $Z$ will be less than a certain value z integrating $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over the corresponding area: 
$$
P(Z<z)=F_{Z}(z)=\ln(z)+\int_{\ln(z)}^{1}\int_{0}^{\ln(z)/x}\,dy\,dx 
$$
I got the limits of the integral from a plot of $y=\ln(z)/x$ vs $x$. From this i get: 
$$
F_{Z}(z)=\ln(z)[1-\ln(z)]
$$

Here is the problem, if I replace $z=e$ in $F_{Z}(z)$ I should get $1$, since the probability of $Z$ being smaller or equal to $e$ is $1$, right? So there is something wrong with my solution, but i just can't find it. Help!

Comment: Hi there! Where do you mean? I have: $F_{Z}(z) = ln(z)+\int_{ln(z)}^{1}\int_{0}^{ln(z)/x}dydx = ln(z) + \int_{ln(z)}^{1}\frac{ln(z)}{x} dx = ln(z)+ln(z)[0-ln(z)]=-ln(z)^{2}+ln(z)=ln(z)[1-ln(z)]$

Comment: Well, just found my mistake though! I was evaluating $ln(x)$ in $x=ln(z)$ as $ln(z)$ and its $ln(ln(z))$! Thank you!

Comment: The question is to find $P(XY < \ln z)$. Draw a graph and it should be clear.

Comment: I would suggest to start by identifying the distribution of $XY$. There, the logarithmic transform is useful: $\ln XY = \ln X + \ln Y$. And $ - \ln X$, $-\ln Y$ are exponential with parameter $1$. Then write density for the sum. After that, you should transform the density according to the exponentiation.

Comment: Hi I found my mistake, it was evaluating $ln(x)$ in $x=ln(z)$ as $ln(z)$ instead of $ln(ln(z))$. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was evaluating $\ln(x)$ in $x=\ln(z)$ as $\ln(z)$ instead of $\ln(\ln(z))$ in the integral. Here is the correct procedure:

$F_{Z}(z)=\ln(z)+\int_{\ln(z)}^{1}\int_{0}^{\ln(z)/x}dydx$

$= \ln(z)+\int_{\ln(z)}^{1}\frac{\ln(z)}{x} dx$

$= \ln(z)+\ln(z)\left(\ln(1)-\ln(\ln(z))\right)$

$= \ln(z)-\ln(z)\ln(\ln(z))$

Replacing $z=e$ I should get $F_{Z}(e)=1$

$F_{Z}(e)=\ln(e)-\ln(e)\ln(\ln(e)) = 1 - 1\ln(1) = 1 - 0 = 1$